# What's the difference between similarly rated DC motors with different nominal voltages?

Tags: dc-motor

I'm looking at a [datasheet](https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/root/8841086664734/EN-86.pdf) that describes several versions of the "same" DC motor. The versions are mostly similar (e.g. same size, no-load speed...) except for the nominal voltage, no-load current and nominal torque. What's the internal differences between these versions (your guess)? and what are the pros and cons of choosing one over the other?

Comment: For mechanically similar motors the amp-turns delivered are ABOUT the same at all voltages. So magnetically the interals see much the same conditions.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What does this mean in plain words? That we get roughly the same torque for the same amount of current?

Comment: Consider a brushless motor with a permanent magnet rotor. How the rotor behaves depends on what flux is applied by the stator coils. Parameters include magnitude, duration and location for each coil concerned. If a north pole field of 1 Tesla is applied to a winding as part of a sequence for 1 ms at a time the when say 1000 Amp-turns are applied to a stator coil, the rotor "doesn't care"  if this is from 10 turns x 100A, 100 turns x 10A, 20 turns x 50A etc. Depending on the voltage different numbers of turns and resistance and current may be needed to get 1000 At.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mechanically similar motors, the difference is the number of turns and the diameter of the wire on the rotor. One motor might use 200 turns of 1 mm<sup>2</sup> wire, another wound for half the nominal voltage may use 100 turns of 2 mm<sup>2</sup> wire. This means they have the same number of Ampere.Turns when running at the same power. They'll produce exactly the same heat from the rotor.They produce different motors simply for the convenience of being able to run them from different nominal voltages.

However ... Wire is only available in certain sizes, there may not be exactly the 'right' size available for the next voltage. The ratio of copper diameter to insulation thickness will not necessarily remain constant. Thicker wire is difficult to pull tight round the poles, so you may get fewer turns than the ratio suggests than with thinner wire. You can only use an integer number of turns. The air resistance of different wire thickness will be slightly different. All these differences mean there will be subtle, or even not so subtle, differences in the motor performance, especially with motors at the extreme end of the range.

All the motors in the datasheet have nominally the same speed, torque and power, with the exception of the torque of the 6 V motor, which is lower. Maybe this is due to the thicker wire meaning fewer turns on the rotor?

While the mechanical, rotor, heat are all nominally the same, the commutator will be running at a high current in the lower voltage motors. This may mean they need uprated or wider brushes, or that the brushes and sliding contacts don't last as long. The commutator in the higher voltage motor is subject to a higher voltage, as the rotor has a higher inductance. This may mean they need bigger gaps, or higher resistance brushes, or that the edges of the commutator don't last as long.

Comment: Ah good answer. But is it mostly for convenience? I was thinking that since the higher voltage motor will have less current, there will be less tear due to heat, so it should last longer?

Comment: @user2251965 No, heat is the same. However you did prompt me to include the one thing I forgot in my answer, the commutator.

Comment: Mostly all that changes is the winding impedance and RPM/Torque slopes. It’s an 8 phase single pole motor. Imagine 8 strand Litz wire in parallel or in single strand in series so the current per strand is the same with many variations in between.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the difference is the diameter of the windings and the resistance caused to keep an equivalent amount of tourque to reach those speeds.

Specific differences will involve looking at the torque vs speed graph, how they build the motor can change this relation, while 2 motors may have the same stall torque and max speed, they can vary widely in how that relationship changes.

Equally there can be perks to using lower voltage motors than your supply voltage  with similar specifications, e.g. in servo motors, it means in short bursts you can vastly exceed that rating,

Comment: Isn't it generally the case that the relation between torque and speed is approximately linear? If so, shouldn't the same stall torque and max speed approximately give the same torque vs speed graph?

Comment: you have a few variables in the mix, what ends up defining the top speed is a combination of friction be it the bearings, some vortex's in the core, or  even the brush pressure, vs how much torque can be extracted when approaching the back emf voltage, this means for most motors the relationship is not quite linear, just where its 0 speed and max speed can end up in the same places, that torque is derived by phase angle / current-turns, so that is more linear to the slip angle.